# Failing to send() 1 wei from one contract to another

Tags: payable, address.transfer, fallback-function, receive

The following code is supposed to send 1 wei from the current contract to a newly created contract. The recipient contract gets created successfully and the sending contract has a positive balance, but the call to send() fails.

```
address payable this_addr = address (this);
require (this_addr.balance > 100000);

MyContract mc_new = new MyContract ();
address payable mc_new_addr = address (mc_new);
bool success = mc_new_addr.send (1);
```

Here is the relevant code from the contract being created. I can see that the contract never has a balance and neither recieve() nor fallback() is ever called.

```
contract MyContract
{
    bool receive_called;
    bool fallback_called;

    constructor () payable
    {
        receive_called = false;
        fallback_called = false;
    }

    receive () external payable
    {
        receive_called = true;
    }

    fallback () external payable
    {
        fallback_called = true;
    }
}
```

The transfer() function doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Also, what triggers calls to receive() and fallback()? Can it only be done by using one of the assembly functions? Or is the a way to trigger these function calls in ordinary solidity?

Comment: You should first make sure you have that one wei in your contract (the one which implements the function which does `MyContract mc_new = new MyContract ();
address payable mc_new_addr = address (mc_new);
bool success = mc_new_addr.send (1);`).

Comment: BTW, as it stands, the constructor of `MyContract` doesn't need to be declared `payable`, since you're not passing any value to it when you call `new MyContract()`.

Comment: The contract does have at least 1 wei. It has several ether.

Comment: Please prove it (add relevant on-chain and off-chain code).

Comment: I've edited the code in my question to show the latest test I ran. It did not revert. The problem is not lack of funds.

Comment: Maybe setting those state variables from `false` to `true` causes your fallback/receive functions to exceed the gas stipend (2300 gas) allowed for them. Try to initialize those variables to `true`, and then set each one of them to `false` in the corresponding function.

Comment: I think that was the problem. When I comment out the code in receive() and fallback(), it works. I can see the balance of 1 wei. Changing the variables from false to true didn't seem to make a difference. And increasing the amount I send to the contract didn't work either. But since it worked with those lines of code commented out, I'm thinking that was the problem.